# Update custom field via visualforce page and save the record

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, controller

What I would like to do is to update particular field with a visualforce button as well as with the respective controller and save the record. Could you please advise how this can be achieved? Could you please add an example code.

In the following converstaion:
[Update custom field using Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99485/update-custom-field-using-trigger/99488?noredirect=1#comment133061_99488)

I've tried to update the field via trigger but it turned out to be difficult.

Therefore I strive to find a way to update the field via controller.

Please advise how this can be achieved.

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: what is the object name.

Comment: the field name is Lead.Status__c. It is the status of the Lead object. 
What I am trying to achieve is to set the Lead.Status__c to 'Existing Deal' when I am trying to convert Lead to Account and the Lead is not converted.
The Lead is not converted to Account when the company name and the url fields coincide with the company name and the url of the Account.
Please advise how this can be achieved in Visualforce via controller?